# How to share a reference to a component's 2d array with another component?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am trying to build a Game of Life application in Angular. I have a  `grid` component for displaying the Game of Life grid with each cell either dead or alive (it does not have any Game of Life logic itself, just displays a clickable grid of cells). The `grid` component has a 2d `gameplane: bool[][]` array to represent the Game of Life grid; the information of each cell is stored in that 2d array. The `grid component` also has a `width: number` and a `height: number` property to determine the dimensions of the grid. Each of these two have a setter that resizes the `gameplane` according to the value passed. 
Now I want to somehow "share" those 3 properties with another unrelated component (`control-panel`), which is done through a service (but I could not figure out how). The Game of Life logic should not be in the `grid` component.

My problem now is that I would need to be able to read and set each of the 3 properties in the service as that is where I plan to place the logic; for example I would need to be able to read the `gameplane` property of the component to see how the user set the state of the cells, which happens in the `grid` component itself, and I also would need to write to the `gameplane` property to set each cell's state for the next cycle according to the rules of the Game of Life.

I have tried using rxjs, not really understanding what I was doing, which did not give me the results i want. Here is some code:

grid.component.ts

```
// ... imports ...
@Component({
  selector: "app-grid",
  templateUrl: "./grid.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./grid.component.scss"]
})
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
  mousedown: boolean;
  gameplane: boolean[][];
  isMousedown: boolean = false;
  private _width: number;
  private _height: number;
// logic for click and mouseenter events...
```

grid.component.html (not really relevant for the question)

```
<div>
  <table 
  (mousedown)="isMousedown = true"
  (mouseup)="isMousedown = false" 
  (mouseleave)="isMousedown = false"
  >
      <tr *ngFor="let row of gameplane; index as yCoord">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of row; index as xCoord; trackBy:trackByTd"
        (mousedown)="gameplane[yCoord][xCoord] = !gameplane[yCoord][xCoord]"
        (mouseenter)="invertCellOnMouseEnter(yCoord, xCoord)"
        class="cell"
        >
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

game-control.service.ts (some functions I would need)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GameControlService {


  evolveInterval: 1000;
  isEvolving: boolean = false;

  fillGameplane(state: boolean) {
    // Fills each cell in the gameplane-array in grid.component with 'state' values.
  }

  randomizePlane() {
    // Randomly fills each cell in the gameplane-array in grid.component with either true or false.
  }

  evolvePlane(){
    // Reads the current value of the gameplane-array in grid.component and sets each cell's state
    // depending on the state of the cell's neighbours according to the rules of the Game of Life

  changeWidth(){
    // Changes the width-poperty in grid.component
  }


  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: You could for example, have that `gamePlan` as a subject in the `GameControlService` and subscribe to it from both components to share the value!

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I have tried that without any success, probably because i had no real idea what I was doing. My main problem was that I was unable to share the 2d array. Could you propose an implementation? Could the state of the grid.component properties then be updated by both the service and the grid.component using the subject method? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since you want to share data between two unrelated component, you should use a data service. This article discusses very detail how you should do it (video + code example) https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

```
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }
}

-------------------------------------------

@Component({
  selector: 'component1'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
  }
}


-------------------------------------------
@Component({
  selector: 'component2'
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
    this.data.changeMessage("Update the data")
  }
}
```

**Note:** if you want to share a large amount of complex data, you should consider using redux, or ngrx. This will require a bit of learning. https://medium.com/@cdeniz/getting-started-working-with-ngrx-and-firebase-85832ad85889